# Example MQTT Client Code not working C

Tags: c, eclipse, mqtt

I got the example code from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/c/).
I have the header file `MQTTClient.h` as well.

However when I build I get the errors:

`undefined reference to MQTTClient_create
undefined reference to MQTTClient_connect
undefined reference to MQTTClient_publishMessage
undefined reference to MQTTClient_waitForCompletion
undefined reference to MQTTClient_disconnect`

In the header file these are set up as follows:

```
DLLExport int MQTTClient_create(MQTTClient* handle, const char* serverURI,
    const char* clientId, int persistence_type, void* persistence_context);
```

I am using a Windows 8 machine with Eclipse C/C++ IDE

I also have some paho-mqtt.dll's I'm not sure how to get the example code up and running.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not to sure I understand your question. The header file and the .c file are in the same project. Only the functions that begin with DLLExport have errors

Comment: You need to link against the paho-mqtt.dll in order to have access to those functions.

Comment: How do I do that? Is that done in Eclipse?

Answer (score 10):

It means paho library is not linked. In Linux for a `c` program example you can link paho library by this way:

```
gcc -L{complete path for output folder} {filename}.c -l paho-mqtt3c
```

In my case it looks like:

```
gcc -L/home/jaydev/MQTT/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.c/build/output test2.c -lpaho-mqtt3c
```

Comment: sudo gcc -L MQtttest.c -l paho-mqtt3c                                           
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o: In function `_s
tart':                                                                                   
/build/glibc-mqlSLF/glibc-2.19/csu/../ports/sysdeps/arm/start.S:119: undefined reference 
to `main'                                                                                
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

There is still some error with my linking, any idea what it could be?