# Linking Paho C Mqtt library error in C++ Project

Tags: c++, c, linker, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to include the [MQTT-C-Client-Library](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/c/) in a simple C++ project.
I have included the header file succesfully like this `#include "MQTTClient.h"`. Compiling it in the linux terminal was printing this errors:

```
[xy@localhost mosquittoProject]$ sudo g++ *.cpp -o MQTTTest
/tmp/ccHn3s6m.o: In function `main':
mosquitto_test.cpp:(.text+0x11e): undefined reference to `MQTTClient_create'
mosquitto_test.cpp:(.text+0x13f): undefined reference to `MQTTClient_connect'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I figured out that I need to link the library after some googling: [Example MQTT Client Code not working C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005906/example-mqtt-client-code-not-working-c)

Based on this question and answer I tried compiling it again like this:

`sudo g++ -L/home/xy/Desktop/paho.mqtt.c/build/output/ *.cpp -l paho-mqtt3c -o MQTTTest`

Which compiles fine but when running I get still an error. 
Console commands and output:

```
[xy@localhost mosquittoProject]$ sudo g++ -L/home/xy/Desktop/paho.mqtt.c/build/output/ *.cpp -l paho-mqtt3c -o MQTTTest
[xy@localhost mosquittoProject]$ ./MQTTTest 
./MQTTTest: error while loading shared libraries: libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I replaced the actual username by **xy** in this post.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem looks like the library (libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1) is not on the library path.

It looks like you are linking against the build location of the library and have not installed it to the default system location (e.g. /usr/local/lib) by running `sudo make install`.

By default on Linux the runtime linker searches the locations listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`. if you edit these remember to run `sudo ldconfig` to update the cache.

You can add the location of the library to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable e.g.:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/xy/Desktop/paho.mqtt.c/build/output/ ./MQTTTest
```

Comment: awesome - just published the first test message using the library :)