# Paho MQTT throws undefined reference error during compile

Tags: windows-10, eclipse, c, mqtt

I have a problem using Paho MQTT client in C.

I downloaded the pre built binaries for my system (Windows 10 64) from their [projects page](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.paho/downloads). I unpacked the zip file to a folder in the documents folder, where I also created a .c file with the example at the bottom of the Paho [product page](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/c/). My editor is atom and my compiler is gcc.

When I tried to compile it in Atom, I got this error:

```
undefined reference to MQTTClient_create'
```

So I went searching and found plenty of topics, but I still couldn't figure out, how to resolve this issue. From [this stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005906/example-mqtt-client-code-not-working-c) I gather that it's a linker problem and that I need to link the files during compile, so here's what I tried:

```
gcc MQTT.c -L "C:\Users\Pete\Documents\MQTT on C\Examples\Paho\lib" -l paho-mqtt3c
```

Which still gives me the same `undefined reference` error. When I try to link to the dll of the same name, the compiler does not find the file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was compiling the program with the 32-bit gcc compiler for the 64-bit library. Installing and using MinGW64 worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to know if you have registered the Paho MQTT dll in Windows?

You should have `paho-mqtt3c.dll` as part of the download.

I don't know if this will work for you, but I have the same issue (undefined reference to `MQTTClient_create`)...

- Copy the `dll` file into `c:/windows/system32`
- Run CMD Prompt as Administrator and type:

  `regsvr32 i/ paho-mqtt3c.dll`

Worth a try.

Comment: I had not registered the dll in Windows. When I ran your command for `paho-mqtt3c.dll` I got: "The module "paho-mqtt3c.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found."
It seems to work for the ...cs.dll, but the compiler gives me the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in OS X. This is how I resolved it

1. I compiled the paho-mqtt library in Linux/EC2 instance.
2. Installed all the dependencies:

sudo yum install install build-essential gcc make cmake cmake-gui cmake-curses-gui

sudo yum install cmake

sudo yum  install doxygen graphviz

3. cmake -DPAHO_WITH_SSL=TRUE -DPAHO_BUILD_DOCUMENTATION=FALSE -DPAHO_BUILD_STATIC=TRUE -DPAHO_BUILD_SHARED=FALSE -DPAHO_MQTT_C_PATH=../paho.mqtt.c/ -DPAHO_MQTT_C_LIB=../paho.mqtt.c/src/libpaho.mqtt3as-static.a
4. make
5. make html
6. make install
7. LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ec2-user/paho.mqtt.c/src
8. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
9. sudo ldconfig
10. gcc test1.c -o test1 -lpaho-mqtt3c

Compiled successfully..

11. ./test1

This solution works for OS X as well. Replace step 2 with 
brew install cmake doxygen openssl-devel